# isosceles triangle related problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

The question is

> **In a isosceles $\Delta ABC$ $AB=AC=b$ ,$BC=a$ and $\angle BAC=20°$ . Find the relation between $a and b$**

I used this
$\frac{1}{2} \cdot b^2 sin20°=
\frac{1}{2} \cdot a \cdot √(b^2-a^2/4).$
But then I have to find $sin20°$ which I am unable to do so.Please help out with the correct approach.(This is a subjective question with calculators are not allowed)
You are allowed to use geometry and trignometry.

Comment: Consider a perpendicular dropped from vertex $A$ onto $BC$. Because of isosceles property, this intersects $BC$ at midpoint (call it $M$). Then Iin $\triangle AMC$ you can have $\cos 80^{\circ}=\frac{CM}{AC}=\frac{a/2}{b}$.

Comment: Yes, there's no need to use a sine or cosine rule (How did you derive the expression you claim? I don't see it immediately), just drop a perpendicular and use the definition of cosine as adjacent/hypotenuse.

Comment: @bounceback OP calculated the area of the triangle in two ways.

Comment: Ah, thanks I see